# Passing context to gorilla mux - go idioms

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm reasonably new to golang and am trying to do work out the best way to do this idiomatically.

I have an array of routes I am statically defining and passing to `gorilla/mux`. I am wrapping each handler function with something to time the request and handle panics (mainly so I could understand how the wrapping worked).

I want them each to be able to have access to a 'context' - a struct that's going to be one-per-http-server, which might have things like database handles, config etc. What I don't want to do is use a static global variable.

The way I'm currently doing it I can give the wrappers access to the context structure, but I can't see how to get this into the actual handler, as it wants that to be an `http.HandlerFunc`. I thought what I could do is convert `http.HandlerFunc` into a type of my own that was a receiver for `Context` (and do similarly for the wrappers, but (after much playing about) I couldn't then get `Handler()` to accept this.

I can't help but think I'm missing something obvious here. Code below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "html"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Context struct {
    route *Route
    // imagine other stuff here, like database handles, config etc.
}

type Routes []Route

var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        index,
    },
    // imagine lots more routes here
}

func wrapLogger(inner http.Handler, context *Context) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        start := time.Now()

        inner.ServeHTTP(w, r)

        log.Printf(
            "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s",
            r.Method,
            r.RequestURI,
            context.route.Name,
            time.Since(start),
        )
    })
}

func wrapPanic(inner http.Handler, context *Context) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                log.Printf("panic caught: %+v", err)
                http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
            }
        }()

        inner.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func newRouter() *mux.Router {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        // the context object is created here
        context := Context {
            &route,
            // imagine more stuff here
        }
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(wrapLogger(wrapPanic(route.HandlerFunc, &context), &context))
    }

    return router
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // I want this function to be able to have access to 'context'
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print("Starting\n");
    router := newRouter()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", router))
}
```

Here's *a* way to do it, but it seems pretty horrible. I can't help but think there must be some better way to do it - perhaps to subclass (?) `http.Handler`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "html"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc ContextHandlerFunc
}

type Context struct {
    route  *Route
    secret string
}

type ContextHandlerFunc func(c *Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)

type Routes []Route

var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        index,
    },
}

func wrapLogger(inner ContextHandlerFunc) ContextHandlerFunc {
    return func(c *Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        start := time.Now()

        inner(c, w, r)

        log.Printf(
            "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s",
            r.Method,
            r.RequestURI,
            c.route.Name,
            time.Since(start),
        )
    }
}

func wrapPanic(inner ContextHandlerFunc) ContextHandlerFunc {
    return func(c *Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                log.Printf("panic caught: %+v", err)
                http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
            }
        }()

        inner(c, w, r)
    }
}

func newRouter() *mux.Router {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        context := Context{
            &route,
            "test",
        }
        router.Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            wrapLogger(wrapPanic(route.HandlerFunc))(&context, w, r)
        })
    }

    return router
}

func index(c *Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q secret is %s\n", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path), c.secret)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print("Starting\n")
    router := newRouter()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", router))
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://github.com/alexedwards/stack - It provides a nice abstracting for stacking middlewares (handlers) with an easy way to pass context through the chain.

Comment: Gorilla itself has a context package.

Comment: @freeformz Gorilla's context package is intended for request context, rather than program context. In particular, it is cleared automatically at the end of a request (if you are using gorilla/mux).

Answer (score 9):

I am learning Go and currently in the middle of a nearly identical problem, and this is how I've dealt with it:

---

First, I think you missed an important detail: There are no global variables in Go. The [widest scope you can have for a variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) is package scope. The only true globals in Go are [predeclared identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers) like `true` and `false` (and you can't change these or make your own).

So, it's perfectly fine to set a variable scoped to `package main` to hold context for your program. Coming from a C/C++ background this took me a little time to get used to. Since the variables are package scoped, they do not suffer from [the problems of global variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/41651). If something in another package needs such a variable, you will have to pass it explicitly.

Don't be afraid to use package variables when it makes sense. This can help you reduce complexity in your program, and in a lot of cases make your custom handlers much simpler (where calling `http.HandlerFunc()` and passing a closure will suffice).

Such a simple handler might look like this:

```
func simpleHandler(c Context, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // FIXME Do something with our context
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}
```

and be used by:

```
r = mux.NewRouter()
http.Handle("/", simpleHandler(c, r))
```

---

If your needs are more complex, you may need to implement your own `http.Handler`. Remember that an `http.Handler` is just an interface which implements `ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`.

This is untested but should get you about 95% of the way there:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

type complicatedHandler struct {
    h    http.Handler
    opts ComplicatedOptions
}

type ComplicatedOptions struct {
    // FIXME All of the variables you want to set for this handler
}

func (m complicatedHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // FIXME Do stuff before serving page

    // Call the next handler
    m.h.ServeHTTP(w, r)

    // FIXME Do stuff after serving page
}

func ComplicatedHandler(o ComplicatedOptions) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return complicatedHandler{h, o}
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
// FIXME: Add routes to the mux

opts := ComplicatedOptions{/* FIXME */}
myHandler := ComplicatedHandler(opts)

http.Handle("/", myHandler(r))
```

For a more developed handler example see [basicAuth in goji/httpauth](https://github.com/goji/httpauth/blob/master/basic_auth.go), from which this example was shamelessly ripped off.

---

Some further reading:

- [A Recap of Request Handling](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/a-recap-of-request-handling)
- [Making and Using HTTP Middleware](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware)
- [justinas/alice](https://github.com/justinas/alice) (for chaining lots of handlers)